# Fail saving changes to database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to do a windows form application with database.

I amke the database and i added entity framework.

This is the code I use to add data in database:

```
public void AddProductToDataBase()
    {
        try
        {
            DataBase _db = new DataBase();
            var item = new Products();
            item.Title = title.Text;
            item.Subtitile = subtitle.Text;
            item.Description = description.Text;
            item.Price = float.Parse(price.Text);
            _db.Products.Add(item);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Product successfully added!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            title.Clear();
            subtitle.Clear();
            description.Clear();
            price.Clear();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Everything seems to work correctly, no error message and message "Product seccessfully added" apear, but when i look into database there is nothing.

I search before to post here and i found that visual studio is making a copy of database and if you change "Copy to output Directory" property of Database to "Copy if newer" it should work right, but it doesn't, I make the same chage to entity framework, still same, nothing changed.

What can i do add data in the correct database? And i also need the program to be portable.

Thanks!!

EDIT: This is DataBase.Contex.cs

```
namespace OlxSelenium
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class DataBase : DbContext
    {
        public DataBase()
            : base("name=DataBase")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Photos> Photos { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your DataBase object defined? I see no reference to the Entity in your code.

Comment: This is how i make the reference http://postimg.org/image/4w1s4x4mn/
Is it wrog?

Comment: Unfortunately the link doesn't show a screen shot. :(

Comment: http://imgur.com/khhXmRy

Comment: You have to reference your DatabaseEntities1 in your code.
e.g. using a using statement.
using (DataBaseEntities context as new DataBaseEntities())
{
    //code to handle data, use context to access your table in the db
}

Comment: using(DataBase _db = new DataBase())
                {
                    var item = new Products();
                    item.Title = title.Text;
                    item.Subtitile = subtitle.Text;
                    item.Description = description.Text;
                    item.Price = float.Parse(price.Text);
                    _db.Products.Add(item);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
like this ?

Comment: You used Entity Framework to create a model for your existing database, right? From your screenshot I gather that you have. So instead of using (DataBase _db = new DataBase()) use the following
using (DataBaseEntities1 context as new DataBaseEntites1())
{
    ....
    context.Products.Add(item);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

Comment: is not working, it give me some errors: invalis expresion as, invalid expresion )

Comment: can you share your project with me?

Comment: telling you here ? or we can make a chat

Comment: let's chat in a session.

Comment: i don't have enough reputation, can you start the chat ?

Comment: Can you initiate a chat?

Comment: no, i don't have enough reputation

Comment: give me a few minutes

Comment: Is your EDMX in a separate project?

Comment: no, is in the same one

Comment: How does your DataBase.Context.cs file look? Can you paste the code or share it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
try
{
using (DataBase context = new DataBase())
{            
       Products item = new Products();
       item.Title = title.Text;
       item.Subtitile = subtitle.Text;
       item.Description = description.Text;
       item.Price = float.Parse(price.Text);
       context.Products.Add(item);
       context.SaveChanges();

       MessageBox.Show("Product successfully added!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
       title.Clear();
       subtitle.Clear();
       description.Clear();
       price.Clear();
}

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: the problem wasn't to add data into database, the problem is to add data into correct database.I can write and read into/from database, but in the copy, i want to add data into the original database

Comment: Did you not map the original db as described in your Database.context.cs file? The code I provided makes an insert into the original db not just in memory.